# Does a gas condenses above its dew point?

Tags: thermodynamics

We all know that at temperatures much below the boiling point, evaporation occurs and liquid/vapor equilibrium exists. 
So if we have steam at temperature greater than dew point, does it undergoes condensation at that temperature?

Comment: Liquid/vapor equilibrium will exist at some point in a CLOSED container.  Steam at a temperature greater than its "dew point" (or condensation point) is common and is known as superheated steam.  Superheated steam will not condense until it is cooled to its condensation temperature.

Comment: So, my question is why evaporation/condensation occurs below the dew point and not above it?

Comment: Water has a vapor pressure at any given temperature.  When the partial pressure of water vapor in air is at the vapor pressure, it will begin to condense.  This partial pressure varies with temperature, and is known as 100% relative humidity.  The temperature at which you reach 100% relative humidity is the dew point temperature.

Comment: Shah M Hasan, you really should do some background research on the Antoine equation, relative humidity, Dalton's law, and Raoult's law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's, for simplicity, consider a closed container with a liquid. In such closed system, evaporation and condensation happen simultaneously.

The rate of evaporation increases with temperature. The rate of condensation, which happens when vapor molecules hit the surface of the liquid, depends on the vapor pressure.

At equilibrium, the rates of evaporation and condensation are the same and the temperature is a dew point, by definition.

If the temperature is raised above that point, the rate of evaporation will exceed the rate of condensation, but, the condensation will still occur. This will continue until the new equilibrium is achieved, with the new temperature becoming a new dew point.

So, for a closed system, condensation does happen at temperatures above the dew point.

In an open environment, when the vapor does not come in contact with liquid, the condensation, generally, should not occur above the dew point.

Comment: So, according to you, the liquid/vapor mixture (say in a closed container) exits even after we go above the dew point?

Comment: @ShahMHasan To a certain point. If we keep raising temperature and there is enough room in the container, all liquid will eventually turn into vapor, i.e., there won't be  liquid/vapor mixture any more. But at lower temperatures, raising the temperature will just shift the equilibrium point to a higher vapor pressure.

Comment: @ShahMHasan ...and, once the equilibrium has been reached, the new temperature becomes a new dew point. This is because, in equilibrium, the vapor is saturated and the dew point is defined as the temperature at which the vapor becomes saturated. In an open environment, the temperature has to be decreased to bring the vapor to saturation, but, in a closed container, the amount of vapor is increased instead.

Answer (score 1):

The dewpoint is the temperature at which the equilibrium vapour pressure of the liquid phase (ie the pressure of the vapour that is in equilibrium with the liquid in a sealed container with no air present) concides with the partial  pressure of the vapour phase in the  atmosphere. At temperatures above the dewpoint the  liquid will tend to turn into vapour and liquid  droplets will shrink. At temperatures below the  dewpoint vapour will tend to turn to liquid  and the droplets will grow in size. (This assumes Dalton's law of partial pressures that says that the total pressure is the sum of the partial pressures of the vapour and any other gas present,  such as air.)

Answer (score 0):

The dew point is defined as the temperature at which, if air is cooled, condensation can begin to occur.  So, by definition, above the dew point, condensation can't occur.